# Updating a component based on the actions in another component

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, vaadin, boot

I have a profile page, where one can edit name+profile picture.
I have a mainlayout (just like in the basic vaadin example) which displays these two (classes Text, Image) based on the user profile.

When changes are made on the profile page (to the UserProfile), how can I trigger an update in mainlayout?

I don't need any component based events like click, or an event source, I just need to tell the MainLayout class to refresh itself based on the UserProfile.

I tried SpringBoot events (they don't work)
I tried using the Vaadin events based on the documentation, but I don't see a relation to my problem anymore after reading that.

Code:

```
  MainLayout.java
     private Footer createFooter() {
        Footer layout = new Footer();

        Optional<Models.UserProfile> maybeUser = authenticatedUserHolder.getProfileUser();

        if (maybeUser.isPresent()) {
            Models.UserProfile userProfile = maybeUser.get();

            //this needs to update when the UserProfile changes in the other component
            avatar = new Avatar(userProfile.getName());
            Util.setImageFromProfile(userProfile, avatar);
             ...

            MenuBar userMenu = new MenuBar();
            //this needs to update too when the UserProfile changes 
            userNameText = new Text(userProfile.getName());
            footerDiv.add(userNameText);
    

    UserProfilePage.java
     TextField name = new TextField("Your name");
        name.setValue(profile.getName()!=null ? profile.getName() : "");
      ...
        name.addBlurListener(e -> {
            log.info("Name: {}", name.getValue());
            profile.setName(name.getValue());
            userService.update(profile);
            // AND HERE I NEED TO DO SOMETHING? SO THAT THE MainLayout fields change, thank you
        });
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all solution.  The most common options are:
use a bus (your DI usually has one, or use a library) -or- search the
parents for the MainLayout and do the change there -or- reload the page.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for @cfrick, issue can be closed, thx.